# Greeks of caps,floors and swaptions

Tags: greeks, swaption, cap

I will have an interview for a junior position as interest rates volatility trader.
I would like ask you some questions about greeks of caps floors and swaptions.

Are Caps vega positive? Are floors and swaptions too?

A spread volatilty trading usiing caps/floors differs from a trade using swaptions from the rate on which I am referring too right?

For instance: If I have a view on volatility term structure of eg: Libor I should use a combination of cap/floor ( like long cap on 30yrs rates and short caps on 10yrs if i think that volatility of 30yrs rates should increase realtive to 10yrs). Instead if I have a view on volatility term structure of Swap rates I should use swaptions right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would the following be fair assumptions to make regarding your question? 1) You are referring to *market standard* LIBOR caps, floors and swaptions (fixed vs LIBOR) 2) You are using a *market standard* model, e.g. Black / Bachelier, with the corresponding strike-dependent *implied vol* taken as input, potentially from another model such as SABR. 3) You are referring to a vega with respect to that implied vol, i.e. for the implied vol at a given strike?